# Using variable from EJS in and EJS if statement

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

Basically, I can't figure out how to use an EJS "variable" (don't know the real name for it. In my case it's `<%=postContent[i]%>`) within an EJS if statement as shown below.

```
<% for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) { %>
    <% if (<%-postContent[i]%>.includes('gyfcat')) { %>
        <div>PLACEHOLDER</div>
    <% } else { %>
        <img src="<%=postContent[i]%>" class="redditImages">
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

I basically want it so when the string `"gyfcat"` is in the `postContent` string (it's a URL), the first block of code runs, else, runs the `<img>` code.

The error I'm getting is `Error: Could not find matching close tag for "<%".`

Comment: It would help if you could paste the code as text rather than attaching a screenshot.  :)

Comment: try using a - instead of a =  <%-postContent[i]%>

Comment: Sorry Adriano lol, noted for next time, thanks. Also your solution didn't work, user, but thanks :)

Comment: Looks like you’re missing %> after (gyfcat)

Comment: Richlewis: I have one right after postContent[i]

Comment: Also in your for loop where us postContent defined? It’s an array I’m assuming? You may need i <= postContent.length rather than hard coding 10

Comment: Just testing with 10 units for now. But yes, you're right. That is what I'm doing once I figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: Can you re write this question please, show us what postContent is ( not declared in the loop? How can you access it?, very difficult to keep looking at the screenshot and not really helpful to people who may reference this question in the future, thanks

Comment: With all due respect, this post isn't about postContent as an array. I'm wondering how to include an EJS variable on the same line as a control flow within an if statement.

Comment: What happens if you remove the <% around postContent as you are already in a if block. Maybe they are not required. I can’t test this on my laptop as on phone

Comment: I'd say `if (postContent[i].includes('gyfcat'))` but I have no idea if that will work. You aren't really supposed to do this anyway; determine the final data structure in your node code, before sending it to `.render()`. Plus, `.includes` is for Arrays, but judging from the code, `postContent[i]` is a string.

Comment: Didn't work :/ thanks though.

Comment: If this is still unanswered in the morning I’ll take a look when I get up

Comment: Thank you. All the help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `if (postContent[i].includes('gfycat'))` works for me. If it doesn't for you, provide the error you get and describe what else is happening. (also note that it's `gfycat`, you have `gyfcat`)

Comment: oh what the hell, it's working now using your method that I already tried Chris haha. I must've mistyped or something. Anyhow, thanks a lot, works now exactly as intended. Cheers.

Comment: Do you wanna create the answer?

Comment: Nah, but I'll point you to jade/pug, which is ten times more readable: https://pastebin.com/8ev5ph5z

Comment: Could you please edit your question to convert the image to text? Even if you already solved your problem, it's more useful to future viewers of the question if they can copy/paste text rather than typing it all out from an image.

Comment: yep, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Simply removing the `<%=` and `%>` around `postContent[i]` solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div> 
    <% if(typeof datas !='undefined') { %>
    <% datas.forEach(function(data) { %>
       <div> Id:<%= data.id %></div>
       <div> Title:<%= data.title %></div>
       <div> Body:<%= data.body%></d>
    <% }); %> 
    <% } %>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.